# How do I get Serena to follow me after I completed the dawnguard quest line?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I completed the dawnguard quest line and after killing Harkon I asked Serena to make me a vampire so I could travel back the soul cairn and get valerica to come back to tamriel. Than I cured myself of being a vampire and I got Serena to do the same. A few days later she came back to the dawnguard castle and after telling me she was now a human, I was not able to start a conversation with her. She would only say "yes?" Or "what do you need?" And that was it.

Comment: Serana has a bug where she is dismissed and won't give you the option of her following again. This is already covered in another question (now linked). If the answers to that question don't help, please explain that here, so that you can get the additional information you need.